# Microchip SEC1210 - Missing Files

Tags: microchip

I've registered a new case at Microchip Support, asking for missing files in documentation (5 days ago and there is no answer).
I trying to use SEC1210 UART ( http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001977A.pdf )
In CCID driver (pg 2) is needed some files to serial mode work properly, so, i need thoses files, can someone help me ? or can someone explain, what i need to change to make serial comunication to work properly ?